# Drop rows in pandas dataframe depending on order and NaN

Tags: pandas, nan, drop, group

I am using pandas to import a dataframe, and want to drop certain rows before grouping the information.

How do I go from the following (example):

```
    Name1   Name2   Name3
0   A1  B1  1
1   NaN NaN 2
2   NaN NaN 3
3   NaN B2  4
4   NaN NaN 5   
5   NaN NaN 6
6   NaN B3  7
7   NaN NaN 8
8   NaN NaN 9
9   A2  B4  1
10  NaN NaN 2
11  NaN NaN 3
12  NaN B5  4
13  NaN NaN 5
14  NaN NaN 6
15  NaN B6  7
16  NaN NaN 8
17  NaN NaN 9
```

to:

```
    Name1   Name2   Name3
0   A1  B1  1
3   NaN B2  4
6   NaN B3  7
8   NaN NaN 9
9   A2  B4  1
12  NaN B5  4
15  NaN B6  7
17  NaN NaN 9
```

(My actual case consists of several thousand lines with the same structure as the example)

I have tried removing rows with NaN in Name2 using df=df[df['Name2'].notna()] , but then I get this:

```
    Name1   Name2   Name3
0   A1  B1  1
3   NaN B2  4
6   NaN B3  7
9   A2  B4  1
12  NaN B5  4
15  NaN B6  7
```

I also need to keep line 8 and 17 in the example above.

Comment: When you say that you need to keep 8 and 9, is this fixed? Or you you have a logic for that? (e.g. the last row before non-NA Name1 or the end?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the rows that are either:

- not NA in column "Name2"
- or the last row before a non-NA "Name1" or the end of data

You can use boolean indexing:

```
# is the row not-NA in Name2?
m1 = df['Name2'].notna()
# is is the last row of a group?
m2 = df['Name1'].notna().shift(-1, fill_value=True)

# keep if either of the above condition is True
out = df[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
   Name1 Name2  Name3
0     A1    B1      1
3    NaN    B2      4
6    NaN    B3      7
8    NaN   NaN      9
9     A2    B4      1
12   NaN    B5      4
15   NaN    B6      7
17   NaN   NaN      9
```

Intermediates:

```
   Name1 Name2  Name3     m1     m2  m1|m2
0     A1    B1      1   True  False   True
1    NaN   NaN      2  False  False  False
2    NaN   NaN      3  False  False  False
3    NaN    B2      4   True  False   True
4    NaN   NaN      5  False  False  False
5    NaN   NaN      6  False  False  False
6    NaN    B3      7   True  False   True
7    NaN   NaN      8  False  False  False
8    NaN   NaN      9  False   True   True
9     A2    B4      1   True  False   True
10   NaN   NaN      2  False  False  False
11   NaN   NaN      3  False  False  False
12   NaN    B5      4   True  False   True
13   NaN   NaN      5  False  False  False
14   NaN   NaN      6  False  False  False
15   NaN    B6      7   True  False   True
16   NaN   NaN      8  False  False  False
17   NaN   NaN      9  False   True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `thresh` argument in [df.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

```
# toy data
data = {'name1': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'name2': [np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan], 'name3': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   name1  name2  name3
0    NaN    NaN      1
1    NaN    1.0      2
2    NaN    2.0      3
3    NaN    NaN      4
```

To remove rows with 2+ NaN, just do this:

```
df.dropna(thresh = 2)

   name1  name2  name3
1    NaN    1.0      2
2    NaN    2.0      3
```

If you want to keep lines 8 and 17, you may want to first save them separately in another variable and add them to df afterwards using `df.append` and then resorting by index.